# Window onresize and onload not triggering

Tags: javascript, triggers, window

**Solution**

Solution:

I did modify it and add alerts to notify me when the page was resizing/loading, and they did indeed resize/load. It just wasn't triggering the custom functions added to the .callbacks array when using the c function for some reason. I've decided to just use another code that does indeed work.

Instead of return c(.callbacks); I changed it to:

```
for(each in win_resize.callbacks) {
    win_resize.callbacks[each]();
    }
```

That seemed to do the trick and it works perfectly fine now.
As for the jsHint thing... That seems a little odd that "alert" isn't defined, and when evaluating whether or not a variable is equal to a string when dealing with... A "string", using == will work just fine. I've never run into an issue where it didn't work the way I expected.

I do not need any more help with this, it can be closed now.
Thanks to everyone that did help, or try to help.

===========================================================

**Original Question**

Window.onload and Window.onresize are not triggering.
I'm not sure what's going on here, because I've done this many times before.
It would be pretty easy to solve if there was some sort of error being thrown, but as far as I can tell in the dev console, there are no errors.

This is my code:

```
var each, win_resizing, win_loaded = false;
function c(r, a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7) {
    if (typeof r == 'object') {
        for(each in r) {
            each[r] = c(each[r], a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7);
        }

        return r;
    } else if (typeof r == 'function') {
        return each[r](a1, a2, a3, a4, a5, a6, a7);
    }

    return r;
}

win_load.callbacks = [];
function win_load(call) {
    if (typeof call == 'function') {
        return win_load.callbacks.push(call)-1;
    }

    return c(win_load.callbacks);
}

win_resize.callbacks = [];
function win_resize(call) {
    if (typeof call == 'function') {
        return win_resize.callbacks.push(call)-1;
    }

    return c(win_resize.callbacks);
}

win_load(function() {
    alert("Loaded?");
});

win_resize(function() {
    alert("Resized?");
});

window.onresize = function() {
    if (!win_resizing) {
        win_resizing = setTimeout(function() {
            delete win_resizing;
        }, 50);

        win_resize();
    }
};

window.onload = function() {
    if (win_loaded!==true) {
        win_loaded = true;
        win_load();
        window.onresize();
    }
};
```

I've duplicated the exact code I made and put it in a [jsFiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/aUkw8/).

Comment: I don't think `window resizing` is going to work on jsFiddle since each section is in it's own iframe.

Comment: Yes, I realize this. That's why there is source code; but it's not working for me in any of my browser period. That's the issue. I couldn't care less if jsFiddle doesn't handle onresize events for iframes.

Comment: First suggestion... strip out all the code except for the two listeners for `onload` and `resize`.  See if the alert works then.

Answer (score 0):

Just as a starting point, I put your code into [JSHint](http://www.jshint.com/) and it spit out this list of errors:

> Line 3: if (typeof r == 'object') {
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 3: if (typeof r == 'object') {
>
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> Line 4: for(each in r) {
>
> Creating global 'for' variable. Should be 'for (var each ...'.
>
> Line 4: for(each in r) {
>
> The body of a for in should be wrapped in an if statement to filter
>   unwanted properties from the prototype.
>
> Line 9: } else if (typeof r == 'function') {
>
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> Line 18: if (typeof call == 'function') {
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 18: if (typeof call == 'function') {
>
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> Line 27: if (typeof call == 'function') {
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 27: if (typeof call == 'function') {
>
> Expected '===' and instead saw '=='.
>
> Line 35: alert("Loaded?");
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 39: alert("Resized?");
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 43: if (!win_resizing) {
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 45: delete win_resizing;
>
> Variables should not be deleted.
>
> Line 53: if (win_loaded!==true) {
>
> Missing "use strict" statement.
>
> Line 35: alert("Loaded?");
>
> 'alert' is not defined.
>
> Line 39: alert("Resized?");
>
> 'alert' is not defined.